# Libgdx game crashes in IOS. NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: ios, libgdx, noclassdeffounderror

After a lot of problems i could compile an execute a game in the IOS module of Libgdx (Robovm).
The new problem shows when i click anywhere on the game screen: the game crashes.
Below is listed the stack trace.
I generated another libgdx project (the default project with an image on a red background) and it happens the same; so, i think it isn't the code of my game.
I emulated these devices: Iphone 5S, Iphone 6s plus, Iphone X, Ipad Air 2.

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/robovm/apple/uikit/UIKeyboardHIDUsage
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.iosrobovm.DefaultIOSInput$8.<clinit>(DefaultIOSInput.java:961)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.iosrobovm.DefaultIOSInput.processEvents(DefaultIOSInput.java:766)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.iosrobovm.IOSGraphics.draw(IOSGraphics.java:367)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.iosrobovm.IOSGraphics$1.draw(IOSGraphics.java:241)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.iosrobovm.IOSGraphics$1.$cb$drawRect$(IOSGraphics.java)
    at org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main(Native Method)
    at org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main(UIApplication.java:428)
    at com.mygdx.game.IOSLauncher.main(IOSLauncher.java:19)
 com.mygdx.game: 4837
```

For both projects it's the same stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using old robovm version with new libgdx. UIKeyboardHIDUsage as part of ios13.4 bindings was added in 2.3.10 (recent version is 2.3.12)